# Regex to change text months to numeric

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv, import

I have a huge CSV file (10M records) in the following format.

```
147804,AC,34,15AUG09,09:00,15AUG09,21:00,YYZ,YVR,PLS
147816,AC,34,26AUG09,09:00,01SEP09,21:00,YYZ,YVR,PLS
```

I need to import them into a mysql database. How can I change all the months to numeric months and preferably into yyyy/mm/dd format.
Thanks

Comment: This could be done without a regex, possibly more cleanly - just parse it using PHP's CSV parsing functions, split the date, write value back, done

Comment: Have you already decided that a regular expression is the most suitable solution strategy for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to accomplish with regex and would be error prone. PHP has CSV support built-in and it’s a lot safer.

```
<?php
if (($if = fopen("src_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if (($of = fopen("dst_file.csv", "w")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($cols = fgetcsv($if)) !== FALSE) {
            $cols[3] = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($cols[3]));
            $cols[5] = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($cols[5]));
            fputcsv($of, $cols);
        }
        fclose($of);
    }
    fclose($if);
}
?>
```

I don’t know if it would be more efficient to just store `$cols` in the database or create a new file and import it. I don’t have any benchmarks.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much. I thought I'd run out of memory with this but fgetcsv seems to do it a bit at a time. 15 million records converted in 15 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, this seems to do the trick :

```
echo date('Y/m/d', strtotime('15AUG09'));
```

returns : 2009/08/15.

If you can manage to parse your CSV, you'll get your date in the format you want.